# Image Cover with LaTeX (on WinEdt)

Tags: latex, miktex

Any thoughts on how to put a full image (covering whole page) as a cover for a book I am writing on WinEdt (LaTeX)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved using:

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{textblock*}{297mm}(0mm,0mm)
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{xxx.png}
\end{textblock*}

(Source: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=968)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at TikZ and PGF:[link](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf). It really can't be beat. Here are some examples: [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).